# Hotkey keypress with random delay

Tags: python, python-3.x

My problem is simple, my code need to hotkey the number "1" for simulate the keypress of numbers "2, 3, 4"
Now, i want to put a random delay on it, i mean: when i press number "1" he wait "random seconds" then he simulate the keypress event for number "2" etc, here is my pattern:

```
Press number "1" with hotkey numbers "2, 3, 4"
random seconds
keypress simulate number "2"
random secs
keypress simulate number "3"
random secs
keypress simulate number "4"
repeat when i press again the hotkey number "1"
```

Here my code, with no random delay, how can i put delay on like my example upside? i try with time.sleep but didnt work.

```
import keyboard
import time
import random


def cont():
    while True:
        keyboard.add_hotkey('1', lambda: keyboard.press_and_release('2'))
        keyboard.add_hotkey('1', lambda: keyboard.press_and_release('3'))
        keyboard.wait('esc')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    cont()
```

Comment: where did you use `sleep()` ? You should use it in `lambda`

Comment: Here keyboard.add_hotkey('1', lambda: time.sleep(2), keyboard.press_and_release('2')) but he simulate the keypress after 2 sec withouth pressing the hotkey "1"

Comment: maybe because `add_hotkey` can get more arguments and it treats `keyboard.press_and_release()` as next argument, not as part of `lambda`. You may have to use `( )` to group commands - like `(lambda ... ,  keyboard.press_and_release(...) )` or simply create normal function `def function()` with all code and then use `add_hotkey("1", function)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may treads `keyboard.press_and_release()` as next argument in `add_hotkey`, not part of `lambda` and execute `keyboard.press_and_release()` at start - before you even press key.

You may have to use `()` to group commands in `lambda` like

```
 keyboard.add_hotkey('1', (lambda: time.sleep(2), keyboard.press_and_release('2')) )
```

Or better create normal function and use its name in `add_hotkey()`

```
import keyboard
import time
import random

def function()
    time.sleep(random.randint(1, 5))
    keyboard.press_and_release('2')
    time.sleep(random.randint(1, 5))
    keyboard.press_and_release('3')
    time.sleep(random.randint(1, 5))
    keyboard.press_and_release('4')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    keyboard.add_hotkey('1', function)
    keyboard.wait('esc')
```

---

**EDIT:** if you press `1` two times at once then it will run `function` two times at the same time. If you don't want it then you would have to use some global variable to control if function is still running:

```
import keyboard
import time
import random

running = False # global variable with value at start

def function():
    global running

    if running:
        return

    running = True
    time.sleep(random.randint(1, 5))
    keyboard.press_and_release('2')
    time.sleep(random.randint(1, 5))
    keyboard.press_and_release('3')
    time.sleep(random.randint(1, 5))
    keyboard.press_and_release('4')
    running = False

if __name__ == '__main__':
    keyboard.add_hotkey('1', function)
    keyboard.wait('esc')
```

Comment: This work perfectly, now i understand where's the problem with my using of time.sleep() thanks! I use random.uniform for use decimal too, work perfectly.